# What is the correct method to remove or tighten this splined "nut"?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, bearings, compressors, threads, tools

This photo shows the input shaft of an air compressor head.

The splined cog-looking disc around the shaft is actually a sort of threaded nut which screws into the larger disc around it. It serves to hold in the bearing on this side.

It may be that this part requires a unique, specialized tool - but I suspect there may be something that is "standard" but perhaps uncommon instead. In many environments a compressor head doesn't require such frequent maintenance that a totally unique tool would be inconvenient.

Note the bolt heads around the splined part don't allow for very much clearance - about 3/16" or ~5mm.

I think given some brute force it probably could be unscrewed using a punch or even a screwdriver used as a punch, but I don't want to damage it.

Possibly an adjustable pin spanner might fit - but the only ones I have are pretty lightweight. Also I think the pins would probably pop out of the grooves (they are usually used in holes instead).

This compressor head is vintage, I think about 70 years old.

[image]

Comment: A think a pin spanner is probably the tool it's designed to work with. Also this is going to sound horrible but you might be able to get a pipe wrench on there enough to loosen it. One other idea: you could make a simple custom punch with a cylindrical end to hammer it loose without damaging it.

Comment: @Drew a beefy pin spanner is what I had imagined too. I don't think a pipe wrench would actually cause too much damage given that the "splines" do not mate with anything else other than the tool itself.

Answer (score 1):

The plumber's strap wrench is a very practical tool for this job.

Here is one for $ 15.30 from Amazon, just for illustration.

[image: strap wremch]

Comment: or the chain version, if the chain is the right pitch - [chain wrench](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Kobalt-Fitting-Removal-Tool/1002633392?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-plb-_-google-_-lia-_-208-_-plumbingtools-_-1002633392-_-0&placeholder=null&gclid=CjwKCAiAtej9BRAvEiwA0UAWXoqc7s7HR1egdYydAISu13q7vD2yikFDZmHDbyahd_zM3Jc_3X0Q5xoC3GwQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)